# Smooth vector fields on submanifiolds are smooth along submanifolds

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a 2 dimensional embedded submanifold in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let $X$ be a smooth vector field on $M$. Then, for each $p\in M$ $X_p=\sum_{i=1}^{3}a_i(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial{r}^j}|_{p}\in T_p\mathbb{R}^3$, where $r^i$ are the standard coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

The problem is to show that $a_i\in C^{\infty}(M)$.

Note that $\frac{\partial}{\partial{r}^i}|_{p}$ is a map $C_{p}^{\infty}({\mathbb{R}^3})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. So using the standard trick of taking a standard coordinate $r^k$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ and restricting to $M$ and then evaluating the sum above doesn't immediately work.

Using the characterization of smooth sections in vector bundle theory, one can show the result, since we can realise vector fields along a submanifold as a vector bundle.

Intuitively, if $X$ varies smoothly on $M$ then so should the coefficients.

I was wondering if there is a more straightforward way to prove this.

Comment: What is your definition of smooth vector field?

Comment: I have the same question as @IvinBabu.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p\in M$. Let $(U,\phi)=(U,x^1,x^2,x^3)$ be a chart about $p$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $U\cap M$ is defined by the vanishing of the last coordinate function. Let $(TU,\tilde{\phi})$ be the chart induced by $(U,\phi)$ in $T\mathbb{R}^3$. Note that $X|_{U\cap M}: U\cap M \rightarrow TU$ is smooth. Hence, on $U\cap M$, $\tilde{\phi}\circ X$ is smooth. On $U\cap M$, $(\tilde{\phi} \circ X)(q)=(x^1(q),x^2(q),x^3(q),a_1(q),a_2(q),a_3(q))$ . Hence, on $U\cap M$, each $a_i$ is smooth. As $p$ was arbitrary, each $a_i$ is smooth on $M$.

Answer (score 0):

By the definitions that I’ve studied, a vector field $X$ is smooth if it can be locally expressed as $X=X_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}, X_j$ smooth and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} = \left[\frac{\partial \phi_i}{\partial x_j} \right]$ where $  \phi(x_j) = (\phi_i(x_i))$ is a local trivialisation. Hence by your notations $a_i= X_j \frac{\partial \phi_i}{\partial x_j}$ which clearly is smooth